# Send array from index 1 to function

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I've this function and and I got values which I need to use from `args`

```
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {

   ....

    myFunc(args)
}
```

I need to pass to `myFunc` all the args from `index 1` and not `0`.
of course I can loop and create another array from index 1 but
this duplicate almost all the values except index 0 , is there a way to avoid it in GO?

Comment: Please take the Go tour. It covers all the basics, including this: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the `args` slice, and pass that:

```
myFunc(args[1:])
```

`args` is a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), not an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types). You can (re-)slice slices, which will be a contiguous subpart of the original slice. For example:

```
args[1:4]
```

The above would be another slice, holding only the following elements from `args`:

```
args[1], args[2], args[3]
```

The upper limit is exclusive. A missing upper index defaults to the length, a missing lower index defaults to `0`. These are all detailed in [Spec: Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions).

Note that slicing a slice does not copy the elements: it will point to the same underlying array which actually holds the elements. A slice is just a small, struct-like header containing a pointer to the underlying array.

Note that if `args` is empty, the above would result in a run-time panic. To avoid that, first check its length:

```
if len(args) == 0 {
    myFunc(nil) // or an empty slice: []string{}
} else {
    myFunc(args[1:])
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will use it. is there a better way to use the if(len) else , I dont like the `if else ` in general and try to avoid as much as possible:)

Comment: @RaynD We are branching the code based on a condition, this is exactly what `if` is for. Note that if you have guarantee that the `args` slice will never be empty, you can omit this check.